# Media file type support on browser

Tags: html, tomcat, video, nginx

I have a file server hosted on tomcat. I am using nginx in front of tomcat.
I am using video tag to play videos saved on the server. Some of my media files(eg. .mkv) are not playing in the browser. Some videos are playing but the audio is missing.

Is there any way to support any kind(or atleast the most common video types) to support on browser player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly supported formats are mp4 and ogg..

For reference U can visit these link

[**Reference 1**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

[**Reference 2**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: Thanks!!!
The link explains everything, so for supporting all file types, I have only one option - convert the file into some supported format. Is there any guide for such kind of conversion - my biggest concern is the delay in file open command and extra processing power on the server (more, if there are N users trying to play same file in parallel) in conversion.

Comment: All u have to have the video in MP4 format and convert using this website 
http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg and use as per the html tag specified in the reference... U got to use both the types...